# Issue with "Pre-Launch report" Google play store

Tags: android, google-play

I recently uploaded my app to the Google Play Store but got this pre-launch report in some devices :

```
Issue: Crash of app com.mypackage running instrumentation

ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner}
```

How do solve it ?

Comment: Same here. Occured the first time tody. I can't find any Exception in the logs or see a crash in the screen recording.

Comment: @Alexander you can check my answer below. I have tested and all test passed for all devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer in [Google play Console Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7002270)

As of October 2017, the pre-launch report uses a new crawler to provide a more comprehensive review of your app. To do so, the pre-launch report must temporarily re-sign your APK within our test environment.

If you notice any issues, you can switch back to the previous testing process (which doesn't require APK re-signing):

1. Sign in to your Play Console.
2. Select an app.
3. Select Release
   management > Pre-launch report > Settings.
4. In the 'Pre-launch report version' section, move the Opt-out switch to the right until it turns blue.

I have tested and all test passed for all devices, and no more crash for running instrumentation.